# getting attendance records from database into gridview ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

i have built an attendance sheet using gridview that stores the attendance of employees into database. My attendance Table is like this

```
tblattendance

Att_ID         Emp_ID          Emp_name        Date           Att_status
1               002             xyz           25/05/2016        Absent
2               002             xyz           26/05/2016        Present
```

Now what i am trying to do is that i want to get the attendance records in a gridview in such a way that the total number of absents and presents of a certain employee from a specific date To a specific date is shown. So far i have done the following Code but it displays the absents in one row and the presents in second row of a certain employee. I want it to be displayed in the same row. I havent yet written the Where condition for Date.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Emp_ID, Emp_name, COUNT(Att_status) AS Astatus FROM tblattendance WHERE Att_status='Absent' AND Emp_ID='2' GROUP BY Emp_ID, Emp_name, Att_status",conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da1.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(Att_status) AS Pstatus FROM tblattendance WHERE Att_status='Present' AND Emp_ID='2' GROUP BY Att_status",conn);
            da1.Fill(dt);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

it is done in the pageload.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your view is something like this

```
Emp_Id Emp_name Dates Absent Present
```

Use following SQL to populate your view

```
select emp_id, emp_name, 'from - to dates' as dates,
sum(case when Att_status = 'Absent' then 1 else 0 end) as [Absent],
sum(case when Att_status = 'Present' then 1 else 0 end) as [Present]
from  [dbo].[tblattendance]
where [date] >= CONVERT(date, '05/25/2016') and [date] <= convert(date, '05/27/2016')
group by emp_id, emp_name
```

Replace 'from - to dates' string by required string and put lower and upper bound of dates in the where clause. I inserted 3 record in the table, that's why I have upper bound as 05/27/2016.